# Mock dns resolver answer object in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, dns, mocking, patch

I have a method called _resolve, where all the ip address passed as a list. then i have a function **_query_ptr** inside this i have a resolve_address function which i want to mock this in my test case.
File name: **dns_resolver.py**

```
async def _resolve(self, hosts):
        tasks = []
        for host in hosts:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self._query_ptr(host)))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return dict(results)

async def _query_ptr(self, host):
        async with self._dns_rate_limiter:
            self.logger.debug('Resolving DNS for %s - server: %s', host, self._dns_resolver.nameservers)
            try:
                **result = await self._dns_resolver.resolve_address(host)**
                return host, self._get_first_ptr_record(result)
            except dns.exception.DNSException as ex:
                print("Responses ex ",host)
                self.logger.debug('Unable to resolve DNS for %s - server: %s - Exception: %s',
                                  host, self._dns_resolver.nameservers, ex)
                return host, None

@staticmethod
def _get_first_ptr_record(result):
    if result.rrset:
        return str(result.rrset[0].target)[:-1]
    return None
```

I have tried to mock the **result = await self._dns_resolver.resolve_address(host)** in my test_dns_resolver.py as,

```
@patch('dns_resolver.asyncresolver.resolve_address', new_callable=AsyncMock)
    async def test_dns_resolver_fill_reverse_dns(self, resolve_address_mock):

        mock_ptr = mock.create_autospec(NS)
        instance = mock_ptr.return_value
        instance.target = 'us-smtp-inbound-2.mimecast.com'
        instance.port = 53

        resolve_address_mock.query.return_value = instance

        dns = DnsResolver(Mock())
        ips = ['207.211.30.242', '205.139.110.221', '207.211.30.221']

        result = await dns._resolve(ips)
        valid_values = ['us-smtp-inbound-2.mimecast.com', 'us-smtp-inbound-1.mimecast.com']
        self.assertIn(result['207.211.30.242'], valid_values)
        self.assertIn(result['205.139.110.221'], valid_values)
        self.assertIn(result['207.211.30.221'], valid_values)
```

which is incorrect. I am new to this mock concept. Can anyone help me on this.
Note: This is a coroutine function.